# How to get first element displayed in dom-repeat?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I want to show first element of dom-repeat as display on form. And other should be added by clicking on button. How this scenario could be possible in polymer. As shown in image.

[image]

As shown in above image room#1 should be display by default and from room#2 should be added on click of button.

**code-**

```
 <form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" action="/form/handler">
     <template is='dom-repeat' items='{{ rooms }}'>
        <div class="head">
           <paper-item>
             <div id="line"><span>Room# {{displayIndex(index)}}</span></div>
             <template is='dom-if' if='{{displayIndex != 1}}'>
               <paper-button toggles class=button on-click="deleteRoom"><img src="trash.png" height="20px" width="20px"></paper-button>
             </template>
          </paper-item>
        </div>
        <choice-form room="{{displayIndex(index)}}">{{ item.room }}</choice-form>
    </template>
 </form>
```

Comment: this is not enough information to help you with a solution

Comment: Please post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for my own question.
You just have to call add function once in ready method.
Following is a code.

```
 ready: function () {
      // For default first Room.
      this.push('rooms', { room: "" });  
      this.roomCount = this.roomCount + 1; 
 },
 addRoom: function () {
      this.push('rooms', { room: "" });  
      this.roomCount = this.roomCount + 1;          
 },
```

Answer (score 3):

I would create a new array that only contains the first room (room#1) and on button click add room#2 to that array and then use this array in `dom-repeat` instead of `rooms`.

Comment: Sorry, don't have the time. What's the problem with using 2 arrays and copying items one-by-one on button click?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Your example contains a binding expression inside `dom-if` (i.e., `if="{{displayIndex != 1}}"`), but that's currently not supported in Polymer. You'll need to use a computed [binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed)/[property](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#define-a-computed-property) instead.

I assume `rooms` initially contains one item, and there's a button that adds more items to the array.

This is what that code would look like:

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      rooms: {
        type: Array,
        value: () => ['King']
      },
      _isDeleteHidden: {
        type: Boolean,
        computed: '_lte(rooms.length, 1)'
      }
    },
    _lte(a, b) {
      return a <= b;
    },
    _inc(index) {
      return index + 1;
    },
    _deleteRoom(e) {
      this.splice('rooms', e.model.index, 1);
    },
    _addRoom() {
      this.push('rooms', this._getRandomRoom());
    },
    _getRandomRoom() {
      const ROOMS = ['King', 'Queen', 'Double', 'Standard'];
      return ROOMS[randInt(0, ROOMS.length)]
    }
  });
});

function randInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <paper-button on-tap="_addRoom">Add Room</paper-button>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[rooms]]">
        <paper-item>
          <span>Room #[[_inc(index)]] ([[item]])</span>
          <paper-icon-button hidden="[[_isDeleteHidden]]" icon="delete" on-tap="_deleteRoom"></paper-icon-button>
        </paper-item>
      </template>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/jydmLv?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks for answer, I used hidden for delete button as per your suggestion, and it's work.

Answer (score 0):

Is not very clear, looks you need just to do

```
var myRommObject = {....your-properties};
this.push('rooms',myRommObject);
```

inside the event handler of your button click
have a look [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data) and [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates)